# Why does my Azure deployment still have a 3rd endpoint for Remote Desktop even though I've disabled it?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, azure

I previously enabled remote desktop in my Azure project to allow me to debug in our staging environment.  This added a 3rd endpoint on port 3389 in addition to 80 and 443.

I've finished debugging and disabled remote desktop in the publishing wizard then did another deployment to staging. I then tried to do a VIP swap with our production instance, but Azure admin console is throwing an error due to staging have 3 endpoints and production have 2 (you can't do a VIP swap between instances that have different # of endpoints).

Here's what I've done to verify remote desktop is disabled:

1. I've triple checked that in the publish wizard that I specific to have remote desktop disabled.
2. The .azurePubxml has:

   `<AzureEnableRemoteDesktop>False</AzureEnableRemoteDesktop>`
3. The cscfg has:

   `<Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.RemoteAccess.Enabled" value="false" />`

4.My csdef has:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ServiceDefinition name="mysite.App" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/ServiceDefinition">
<WebRole name="www" vmsize="Small">
<Sites>
<Site name="Web">
    <VirtualApplication name="r" physicalDirectory="../ReviewPost/ReviewPost" />
    <Bindings>
        <Binding name="Endpoint1" endpointName="Endpoint1" />
        <Binding name="Endpoint2" endpointName="Endpoint2" />
    </Bindings>
</Site>
</Sites>
<Endpoints>
  <InputEndpoint name="Endpoint1" protocol="http" port="80" />
  <InputEndpoint name="Endpoint2" protocol="https" port="443" certificate="STAR.mysite.com" />
</Endpoints>
<Imports>
  <Import moduleName="Diagnostics" />
  <Import moduleName="RemoteAccess" />
  <Import moduleName="RemoteForwarder" />
</Imports>
<Certificates>
  <Certificate name="STAR.mysite.com" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" />
</Certificates>
</WebRole>
</ServiceDefinition>
```

Despite the above configuration, the azure console is showing 3 endpoints (port 80, 443 *and* 3389) for the staging environment.

What am I missing?

Comment: I think I answered this over on the MSDN forums but hadn't seen it over here. If my answer over there is good, it would be nice to link from here to there. (I can't easily find the thread anymore.)

Comment: @smarx: I added more comments to this and over at MSDN. From what I can tell, I've set false and disabled to everything in the config files, so it should remove the endpoint.  Is there a bug somewhere?

Comment: Answering over there. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazuredevelopment/thread/32f2c45c-e3f2-404e-a1d5-54b49c57af94/ for those who want to follow along. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on information from @smarx in the [MSDN forums mirror of my question](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazuredevelopment/thread/32f2c45c-e3f2-404e-a1d5-54b49c57af94/) here's the solution:

Remove these lines from your .csdef:

```
<Import moduleName="RemoteAccess" />
<Import moduleName="RemoteForwarder" />
```

These 2 lines control the creation of the extra endpoint even though remote access may be disabled.

Comment: In addition to that you also need to modify your .cscfg files. to remove all RemoteAccess and RemoteForward lines.

Comment: Just to expand on the above comment by TMC, you'll need to remove any setting element (under the ConfigurationSettings element) whose name attribute starts with **Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.RemoteAccess** or **Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.RemoteForwarder**, and remove the Certificate element with name **Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.RemoteAccess.PasswordEncryption**. In my case, build errors ensued until all of the above was purged.